# Question about drawing and replacing a pack of cards

Tags: probability

A card is drawn and replaced in an ordinary pack of 52 playing cards. Minimum number of times must a card be drawn so that there is at least an **even chance** of drawing a heart?

What does the second sentence of the question mean?
Why should there be any change in the chance of drawing a heart, as the cards are being "replaced" (kept back into the pack after drawing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one draw, we have a chance $\frac{1}{4}$ of drawing a heart.
For $n$ cards, the chance we don't draw any hearts at all is $(\frac{3}{4})^n$ as we need (independent, as we put cards back) events of *not* drawing a heart.
So the complementary probability $1-(\frac{3}{4})^n$ computes the probability of drawing at least a heart, which is what was asked.

So for what $n$ (number of draws) does this become $\ge \frac{1}{2}$?

Solve for $n$ using logarithms, say.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks you to find the number of draws such that
$$P(\text{at least one heart has been drawn})\geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

In such cases (when "at least" is at play), it is often useful to look at the probability of the negation ("no hearts are drawn"), i.e.,

$$P(\text{at least one heart has been drawn})=1-P(\text{no hearts have been drawn}).$$

The latter follows a geometric distribution. Try solving it now; if it is still causing you trouble, let me know and I'll come back to you sometime tomorrow.